# How to run a screensaver in 'config' mode with ShellExecute? OS overrides my ShellExecute call

Tags: shell, delphi, command-line, shellexecute, screensaver

I want to run a screensaver in 'config' mode with ShellExec. I use this (Delphi) call:

```
 i:= ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar('c:\temp\test.scr'), PChar('/c'), NIL, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

However, the parameter received by the SCR file is '/S', so somewhere on the road Windows intercepts my call and replaces my parameter with '/S'.

---

Update
I did an experiment:
I built an app (mytest.exe) that shows the parameters. I started mytest.exe with /c as parameter.  The /c parameter is received correctly.
Then I renamed mytest.exe to mytest.scr. Now the parameter sent is overridden by the OS. The parameter received is now '/S'.

Interesting!

Dirty fix: Executing a CMD file that executes the screensaver in /c mode works!

Comment: This is the wrong way to start a process. The correct function is CreateProcess

Comment: Yes. I know. (ShellExecuteEx is also a better option than ShellExecute). But I need a quick (so, dirty is also acceptable) way to fix this now (I have a whole ecosystem built arround ShellExecute).  -- Or you think that calling CreateProcess will fix this? I will look to replace ShellExecute with CreateProcess in the days to come anyway.

Comment: CreateProcess is always the way to start an executable. You should always do it that way. Don't let the shell screw you over.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - You must admit though its beauty. ShellExecute can run *.lnk files and other coll things like 'mailto:' :)

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. ShellExecute is never the right tool. Sometimes ShellExecuteEx is. As in your examples. To create a process use CreateProcess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look in the Registry, you will see that the `open` verb for the `.SCR` file extension is registered to invoke the file with the `/S` parameter by default:

[image]

So, your `/c` parameter is ignored.

If you want to invoke the configuration screen of a `.scr` file, use the `config` verb instead of `open`:

[image]

```
ShellExecute(0, 'config', PChar('c:\temp\test.scr'), nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Running a `.scr` file without any parameters is similar to running it with the `/c` parameter, just without foreground modality, per the documentation:

[INFO: Screen Saver Command Line Arguments](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/182383/info-screen-saver-command-line-arguments)

```
   ScreenSaver           - Show the Settings dialog box.
   ScreenSaver /c        - Show the Settings dialog box, modal to the
                           foreground window.
   ScreenSaver /p <HWND> - Preview Screen Saver as child of window <HWND>.
   ScreenSaver /s        - Run the Screen Saver.
```

Otherwise, run the `.scr` file with `CreateProcess()` instead of `ShellExecute()` so you can specify the `/c` parameter directly:

```
var
  Cmd: string;
  SI: TStartupInfo;
  PI: TProcessInformation;
begin
  Cmd := 'c:\temp\test.scr /c';
  UniqueString(Cmd);

  ZeroMemory(@SI, SizeOf(SI));
  SI.cb := SizeOf(SI);
  SI.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  SI.wShowWindow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;

  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(Cmd), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, nil, SI, PI) then
  begin
    CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
    CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
  end;
end;
```